# boost::bind with maps, what's the difference between binding std::pair and std::map::value_type?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-bind

What's the difference between the following two cases?

```
std::pair<int,std::string> example_1 (std::make_pair (1,"foo"));
int value_1 = boost::bind (&std::pair<int,std::string>::first,_1) (example_1);

std::map<int,std::string>::value_type example_2 (std::make_pair (2,"boo"));
int value_2 = boost::bind (&std::pair<int,std::string>::first,_1) (example_2);
```

The first example works fine but the second does not compile when the binding is done. I have looked at the file `stl_map.h` and `value_type` is defined as follows:

```
typedef std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> value_type;
```

I don't see the difference. I would appreciate is someone can tell let me know and the reason why the second example does not compile.

The compilation error message is:

```
.../include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:333:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_pointer(const std::pair<const int, std::basic_string<char> >&)’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map`'s `value_type` has a `const` key (`const int` in your case), whereas the pair you're using doesn't (plain `int` in your case).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the use of `const` in the map value type. `std::pair<int,std::string>::first` is not an accessible item on `std::pair<const int,std::string>::first`. Yes, there's an implicit conversion defined by pair from the const version to the non-const version, but that conversion isn't considered for the purposes of calling a member function like this. Those uses of `pair` might look similar, but really they are completely independent classes that are unrelated to each other in terms of where field locations and such might go.

In essence, you'e asked boost to build code like

```
std::pair<const int,std::string> example(3, "Hello");
example.std::pair<int,std::string>::first
```

which is not valid.

Comment: Yep, I didn't realize the `const`...neeed more coffee. Thanks!